# Setting msg.value to send value to other contract fails with "function call failed to execute"

Tags: solidity

I try to call a contract method of another contract from my solidity function. The problem is that the function call fails as soon as I add the msg.value argument. The exception is then "Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute"

Contract1

```
function deposit(uint256 amount) payable public {
   IDefiAdapter(defiAdapterAddress).deposit{value: amount}();
}
```

Interface of Contract2

```
interface IDefiAdapter {
  function deposit() external payable;
  function withdraw() external;
  function getBalance() external view returns(uint256 balance);
}
```

I would like to pass the value like this instead of passing it as method param. Without the msg.value added, the call is working.

Do I need to define the interface of Contract2 differently to make it possible or add any additional imports to the Contract2 implementation?

Comment: Your syntax is correct. Does your contract hold enough balance to send the `amount`? Can you share the `deposit()` implementation (including its dependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

solved by removing the amount in the Contract1 deposit() function and replacing the function call with Contract1(address).deposit{msg.value}();